# prestashop product-list.tpl custom add to cart section

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Firstly i have to say i'm new to prestashop and so far i Love the features available. However i have got stuck on something which i feel should be easy. I must be missing something with how the smarty template engine works.

its hard to explain the whole problem with out actually seeing it. at our new site www.eliquidonline.co.uk i'm working on the product listing template and wanted to change how thw look and feel of the show price and ad to cart area looked.

i designed the look whilst a product was on sale so i could add the before price, discount ammount etc. but now i have taken a product off sale this area does not display. You can see for yourself using the link above.

The code i have so far is :

```
{if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE AND ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}
                <div class="pricecontainwrapper">
                <div class="addpricetag">{if isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type='before_price'}
                        <span class="smalltext">Was </span><span class="smallstrike">{if $product.price_without_reduction > 0 && isset($product.specific_prices) && $product.specific_prices && isset($product.specific_prices.reduction) && $product.specific_prices.reduction > 0}
                            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}{displayWtPrice p=$product.price_without_reduction}</span><div class="pricetag">{if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}</div></div><a href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='View'}"><div class="addcartpricebutron">Add To cart</div></a>

                </div>
               {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" id_product=$product.id_product type="old_price"}
                            {if $product.specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage'}
                        <div class="pricereduction">SALE -{$product.specific_prices.reduction * 100}% OFF</div> 

                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="unit_price"}
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type='after_price'}
                    {/if}
                </div>
                {/if}
```

now i presume one of the if statements of the smarty template is not displaying all of the code but can't figure out why. any info on why would be very much appreciated.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Obviously if you don't have a product on sale it's not going to display old price, discount percent and so on since there is no old price or discount.

Answer (score 0):

If your product is put on sale in the product admin page. Then you could access the variable `on_sale`.

Within the foreach loop:

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
    <!-- {$product.on_sale} code here -->
{/foreach}
```

You can access the variable like `{$product.on_sale}`. Like this:

`<div class='{if isset($product.on_sale) && $product.on_sale}your-special-discount-class{/if}'>`